# How to use user uid in firebase to give user permission to read write data in database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making an webapp with firebase and javascript, So i am authenticating user to read write data in firebase database, i have generated user uid but on logging into web-application i cannot see the data in database.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('<?php echo $email; ?>' ,'<?php echo $password; ?>').catch(function(error) 
        {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user)
        {
            console.log(user.uid);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not Signed In");
        }
    });     
});
```

I want to fetch every data from the database. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: The code and screenshot you shared only show Firebase Authentication. How is this related to the Realtime Database? And what line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: currently the situation is when i log in to application it shows users list and there data stored in firebase, but now i have write security rules for database, so after writing rules i cannot see data on frontend, so for that i have performed firebase authentication now what to do after that , to display data on frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're not giving anyone permission to see the data from firebase database based on your rules.

Check out [This link](https://medium.com/@dftaiwo/understanding-the-power-of-firebase-security-rules-part-1-f46aae773a24) on Medium.com it shows some examples on firebase rules.

Comment: Thank you for the response but i have completed this task the same day.